# Weighted integral of a convolution

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

Afer some experiments, it seems to me that:

the integral (in the entire domain) of a **convolution** $(f*s)(x)$, of a *filter* function $f(x)$ with a a *signal* function $s(x)$, multiplied by a *weight* function $w(x)$,

$$ \int (f*s)(x) \cdot w(x) \, dx  $$

, **when all functions are integrable**,

is equal to the integral of the *signal* function $s(x)$ weighted by the **cross-correlation** $(f\star w)(x)$ of the *filter* function $f(x)$ with the *weight* function $w(x)$,

$$ \int (f\star w)(x) \cdot s(x) \, dx $$

Is that right?

If it is, what is the proof?

If it is not, is there something similar that let one merge the filter and the weight functions to create a new weight function?

Comment: (moved from mathoverflow.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this is just changing the order of integration (which has to be justified by integrability conditions):
\begin{align}
\int (f*s)(x)w(x) dx & = \int\int f(y-x)s(y)dy\, w(x)dx\\
& = \int\int f(y-x)w(x)dx\, s(y)dy\\
& = \int (f\star w)(y)s(y)dy.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I was almost reaching that proof, but your answer has a much cleaner formulation.